# OpenCV Object detection becomes erratic when outputting video to a html page and then passing that page to an iframe in another html page

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

I have some open cv object detection output that I need on a webpage. Below is the relevant code block.

**Flask + OpenCV**

```
def gen_frames():  
            
    #Main code body was here but removed because irrelevant to the post

    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    frame = buffer.tobytes()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result

app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',threaded=True)
```

**HTML (index.html)**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

The video output shows up in the webpage as expected.

However when trying to view that output through an iframe in another webpage the object detection goes off whack.

[Here's what the object detection should look like.][1]

[Here's what happens after viewing through the iframe.][2]

The terminal also spits out the following error.

`Assertion avci->compat_decode_consumed == 0 failed at libavcodec/decode.c:731`

Comment: and where is `object detection` code? All problem can be in `object detection`. Code in your question only send image so it can't change boxes on image. All problem has to be before you send it.

Comment: @furas I added the code in

Comment: what is `nomi_izi`? I can't find it on internet. You should put code as text, not link to external page. And if you put it on pastebin then you could select `highlight: Python` and it would be more readable.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas I fixed the issue.

Comment: you could describe it as anwer. And later you can mark your answer as accepted. And few minutes laster you can upvote your answer. You will get few points of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to view the output running through an iframe runs two instances of the app if the original html page is open. Which creates threading issues.

Thus if you are going to view it through an iframe only, keep one instance of the webpage open.